# Bot Protection for Marketing Cloud CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I want to implement Bot protection for Cloudpages that I am building in Marketing Cloud. Client does not want the manual Recaptcha way because that may deflect some leads.

Is there any other automated way/ workarounds that can be implemented?

Comment: You can look into a honeypot implementation, it's rather simple to implement
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx/

Comment: As an additional measure to the honeypot field, I recently implemented a solution that uses javascript to modify the form link. Initially when the page loads, the form is configured to submit data to an invalid link, and only after 2-5 seconds, depending on the length of the form, the link gets replaced with a correct one

Comment: Thanks @JonasLamberty

Comment: I forgot to mention - Make sure to cross-browser test this. I've just run into Edge (who else) autofilling a honeypot :D